# Getting My First Radio(Transceiver)

Tags: antenna-system, icom-ic-705

I'm a prepper based in Pakistan, currently exploring communication options for grid-down scenarios. My recent discovery of ham radio has sparked my interest, both for preparedness and as a hobby. At present, I possess a Bench KH2028 receiver for FM, LW, MW, and SW frequencies. Now, I'm seeking a transceiver that meets specific criteria: compact, lightweight, energy-efficient, dependable, user-friendly, requiring minimal accessories, and most importantly, capable of facilitating global communication.

In Pakistan, the scarcity of amateur radio operators means limited access to repeaters and nearby counterparts. Based on my preliminary online research, UHF and VHF might not be as useful, though I could be mistaken. I'm willing to make a one-time investment in a substantial radio system alongside some inexpensive HTs. I'm open to suggestions regarding bands, modes, or any viable alternatives.

The Icom IC-705 caught my attention, but I'm eager to explore other recommendations that might better suit my needs. Additionally, I'm seeking antennas that align with similar criteria: small, lightweight, energy-efficient, reliable, easy to set up, requiring minimal accessories, and capable of enabling effective communication. ***Remember***, in Pakistan, our radio infrastructure is limited, and my goal encompasses regular use, communication during grid-down scenarios, and emergency relief efforts. Ignore my technical mistakes due to lack of radio knowledge